# Inverse calculation from input fields

Tags: javascript

I got stuck. Want to calculate `Value Four` field from the `Fraction Value` field
The function `calculateFractionValueInPercent` executes good, but after execution function `calculateInverseValue`,  `valFour` equals to `NaN` and `fractionValue` doesn't changes. Please help to figure it out. Thanks

```js
const calculateFractionValueInPercent = () => {

  let valOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valOne').value) || 0;
  let valTwo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valTwo').value) || 0;
  let valThree = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valThree').value) || 0;
  let valFour = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valFour').value) || 0;

  let totalValue = parseFloat(((valFour / ((valOne + valTwo) - valThree)) * 100)).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById('fractionValue').value = totalValue + "%";

};

const calculateInverseValue = () => {

  let valOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valOne').value) || 0;
  let valTwo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valTwo').value) || 0;
  let valThree = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valThree').value) || 0;
  let fractionValue = document.getElementById('fractionValue').value || 0;

  let totalInverseValue = parseFloat(((valOne + valTwo) - valThree) * (fractionValue / 100)).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById('valFour').value = totalInverseValue;

}
```

```html
<label>Value One</label>
<input type="text" id="valOne">
<br>
<label>Value Two</label>
<input type="text" id="valTwo">
<br>
<label>Value Three</label>
<input type="text" id="valThree">
<br>
<label>Value Four</label>
<input type="text" id="valFour" onchange="calculateFractionValueInPercent()">
<br>
<label>Fraction, % </label>
<input type="text" id="fractionValue" onchange="calculateFractionValueInPercent(), calculateInverseValue()">
```

Comment: Can you give us exact steps to reproduce? I played around with it any didn't see NaN pop up.

Comment: Step 1. Fill inputs from `Value One` to `Value Four` and try to change achieved result in the `Fraction` input to another value up to 100. Step 2. Fill inputs from `Value One` to `Value Three` without filling `Value Four` and fill `Fraction` value up to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. The HTML calls `calculateFractionValueInPercent()` when the fraction value is changed. This causes it to read values one through four and update the fraction value, overwriting whatever the user might have just entered.
2. `calculateInverseValue()` does not attempt to read `fractionValue` as a number. Combined with the previous point, this means it's always trying to execute an operation like `"50%"/100` which is NaN as `50%` can't implicitly be coerced to a number.

Not calling `calculateFractionValueInPercent()` on percent value change and ensuring `parseFloat()` on the fractionValue causes the form to work as expected.

```js
const calculateFractionValueInPercent = () => {

  let valOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valOne').value) || 0;
  let valTwo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valTwo').value) || 0;
  let valThree = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valThree').value) || 0;
  let valFour = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valFour').value) || 0;

  let totalValue = parseFloat(((valFour / ((valOne + valTwo) - valThree)) * 100)).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById('fractionValue').value = totalValue + "%";

};

const calculateInverseValue = () => {

  let valOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valOne').value) || 0;
  let valTwo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valTwo').value) || 0;
  let valThree = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valThree').value) || 0;
  let fractionValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('fractionValue').value) || 0;

  let totalInverseValue = parseFloat(((valOne + valTwo) - valThree) * (fractionValue / 100)).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById('valFour').value = totalInverseValue;

}
```

```html
<label>Value One</label>
<input type="text" id="valOne">
<br>
<label>Value Two</label>
<input type="text" id="valTwo">
<br>
<label>Value Three</label>
<input type="text" id="valThree">
<br>
<label>Value Four</label>
<input type="text" id="valFour" onchange="calculateFractionValueInPercent()">
<br>
<label>Fraction, % </label>
<input type="text" id="fractionValue" onchange="calculateInverseValue()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like the other values `fractionValue`too has to be converted into `number`. As it's type is text, you cannot directly use it in arithmetic operations:

```
let fractionValue = parseFloat( document.getElementById('fractionValue').value ) || 0;
```